# Create a new bitmap with double the number of pixels in a previously stored bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, bitmap

First of all, I am picking an image from the gallery and converting it into bitmap.

What i want to achieve is that, when a certain button is pressed, a new bitmap is created with double the number of pixels in the previously stored bitmap. Next, each pixel from the original bitmap should be stored in four pixels around the same co ordinates in the new bitmap.

I have tried looping through both of the bitmaps but I'm getting an error which says **Y SHOULD BE > BITMAP.HEIGHT()**

not sure what I'm getting wrong here.

And even if i fix this error in the loop, can the UI thread even manage to loop through a large number of pixels without becoming unresponsive?

The MainActivity code is pasted below:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
static final int PICK_IMAGE = 11;

ImageView image;

Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button chooseImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_btn);
    Button apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply_btn);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int viewHeight = image.getHeight();
            int viewWidth = image.getWidth();

            int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();
            int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();

            Bitmap betterQuality = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpWidth*2, bmpHeight*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            int newXVal = 0, newYVal = 0, limX = 2, limY = 2;
            int color;
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++) {
                    for (int a = newXVal; a < limX; a++) {
                        for (int b = newYVal; b < limY; b++) {
                            color = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
                            betterQuality.setPixel(a, b, Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), Color.red(color), Color.blue(color), Color.green(color)));
                        }
                    }
                    newXVal++;
                    newYVal++;
                    limX++;
                    limY++;
                }
            }
            image.setImageBitmap(betterQuality);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `betterQuality`. Sorry, but you will not get a better quality if that is where you are after. Only more pixels.

Comment: `bmpWidth*2, bmpHeight*2`. That will give you four times as much pixels. Not double the amount of pixels.

Comment: `Next, each pixel from the original bitmap should be stored in four pixels around the same`. For that you should have more than five times the amount of pixels.

Comment: can you explain why a better quality is not achievable by duplicating pixels? I don't know much about images

Comment: Well think about it: You send me a bad picture. And i double the amount of pixels... would it become a better quality picture? That would be easy!

Comment: Yeah you're right. There is no way to maintain the quality of an image when you zoom in right? Unless it's a vector image?

Comment: Indeed. You need vector for that.

Comment: Thanks :D by the way, can you still write a loop that does this though? Duplicates the pixels? I can't come up with the logic for it.

Comment: Change `newXVal++;
                    newYVal++;
                    limX++;
                    limY++;` to `newXVal++;newXVal++; newYVal++; newYVal++;`.

Comment: Will this fix the error i'm getting that says y should be > than bitmap.height()? and can the UI thread manage to loop through alot of pixels?

Comment: Does it work now? If you mean that it takes a lot of time and that it freezes the gui then put it in a thread or AsyncTask.